# Reference a linked server without specifying server name

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, linked-server

I have a remote server with an SQL Server instance running on it.  I can only access it over a VPN, but my users want to be able to connect to it without using a VPN.

I also have SQL Server running on my computer, and would like the users to connect to the remote server through my computer.  I have read about linked servers, but it seems like I have to use the server name in each query.
For example:

```
select * from [192.168.0.45].[tblUser]
```

I would like other users that use the linked server to only have to use the table name.  For example:

```
select * from tblUser
```

Additionally, when I use a linked server, I have to use "master" in the connection string, even though that is not my database.

Comment: I am not sure if this question is a good fit for SO. You may be better of at server fault or at the database page from stack exchange. Nonetheless I would recommend to include the tag for the Microsoft SQL server version that you are using.

Comment: but this error is related to visual studio config and connection string

Comment: As it happens, I actually needed to do exactly this to test an odd condition today... funny how the world works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unavoidable that you must reference the remote object using a [four-part-name](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1095/sql-server-four-part-naming/), but you can use synonyms to make a remote table look like a local table.

The four-part-name is composed of `[The server name].[The remote database name].[The remote schema (usually dbo)].[The remote table name]` and all parts must be specified for queries made against linked servers.

You can, however, [create a synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190626.aspx) in a local database to avoid having to specify the four-part-name each time you reference the table.

```
CREATE SYNONYM [synonymName] FOR [four].[part].[name].[here]
```

For example, you could proxy an entire database by creating synonyms for each table.  Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'CREATE SCHEMA ['+TABLE_SCHEMA+'];'
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'dbo';

SELECT 'CREATE SYNONYM ['+TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+TABLE_NAME+'] FOR [192.168.0.45].['+TABLE_CATALOG+'].['+TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+TABLE_NAME+'];'
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES];
```

Running such a script will produce a script which you can run on the server you are using as a proxy to create all of the synonyms.

Comment: thanks @Mitch for your edit and answer

Comment: but how i can write a connection string for this structure in web.config ?

Comment: You would create the synonyms in a database on your machine, then connect to that database.  The connection string would be no different from normal.  See http://www.connectionstrings.com/